# Cache Studio not reflecting changes made by custom %Projection.AbstractProjection classes

Tags: intersystems-cache

I sometimes make use of projection classes (subclasses of %Projection.AbstractProjection) to generate various things, and I'm finding that if I use the %Dictionary classes to modify other classes from within the CreateProjection method, the changes make it into ^oddDEF correctly, the changed classes compile and run correctly, but Cache Studio doesn't see the changes, and keeps displaying them the way they were prior to modification.  If I then compile from Cache Studio, it overwrites the changes made by the projection class.

It's fairly "sticky" - if I close the changed classes, remove them from my project, then add them back and open them, the unchanged, cached version is still there in Cache Studio.

I am calling QueueClass on the changed classes, but that doesn't seem to matter.  I'm on 2008.2, in case that matters.

How can I programatically get Cache Studio to update its cache, or otherwise fix this problem in a reasonable way (closing Cache Studio each time isn't really reasonable, for example)?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I thought I'd point out that the [AbstractProjection class documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20111/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Projection.AbstractProjection) notes that its intended use is to generate other external files at compilation time, so you may be using it in an unintended way.  Can you provide additional detail about what you are manipulating in other classes?  We might be able to provide you with a better way to do that.

Comment: @Derek - I'm generating methods, for example.  Note that the classes work fine, just not Cache Studio.

Comment: Sounds like you maybe could be using [Method Generators](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20111/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_methodgen) instead, though admittedly, they're for generating parts of the same class, and not for other classes like what you are doing.  Can I ask why you have one class generating pieces of another class?  It suggests in my mind that you might have multiple responsibilities going on in one or more classes, and that reorganizing your classes might be a better solution.

Comment: @Derek - You will have to trust me that this makes sense.

Comment: OK, fair enough. =D  Sounds like your core issue is simply a bug that should be reported to InterSystems then.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset TimeChanged property of %Dictionary.ClassDefinition

Comment: try this
    $$$defClassKeySet(%class.Name,$$$cCLASStimechanged,$h)
  Do RebuildItemIndex^%R(%class.Name,"CLS")